# Problem with jQuery UI controls size

Tags: jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI. When i am trying to add some controls (DatePicker, Dialog, Autocomplete) they look to large. May be anybody does know what cause of this problem?

Thanks in advise....

Answer (score 0):

They typically use `em` sizes in their CSS, if the container they're in is larger for any reason, they it'll propagate down to the elements.  Try resetting `font-size`, `zoom`, etc to a normal level above where the jQuery UI elements are contained.

Comment: But not only font looks too large. Also paddings, margins , top, left css properties within controls look increased.

Comment: @Glum - It's the CSS of the container you're in that's filtering down, do you have an example page?

Answer (score 0):

Well, hard to say whether you don't like the size of jQuery UI or that they seem larger than they do on this site: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Try removing all existing classes and styles and see how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the containers font-size like:

```
font-size: 80%;
```

or

```
font-size: 0.8em;
```

Ok, but how to resize containers of the absolutely positioned UI items like DatePicker and Dialog? This may prove hard, until a later UI version. In the meantime start your journey from the [multiple ui themes](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/) discussion, especially the [comment 16](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/#commentNumber16).